# Image Gallery Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

i try to use the carousel FredSel gallery. but nothing happend when i clicked on the button to open. The gallery i chosse are the swipe gallery and i have downloaded the libraries from the site. i have tried lots of things but nothing worked.

Someone can help me? i'm new in jquery

i dont know what i do wrong.

this is my code.

```
<script src="jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.0-packed.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.css"> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
$("#foo4").carouFredSel({
    auto        : false,
    swipe       : {
        onTouch     : true,
        onMouse     : true
    }
});
</script>
```

HTML5

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true" data-id="footer">                      
         <a href="#p1" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
         <h1>HOME</h1>
         <a href="#foo4" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" class="ui-btn-right" data-direction="reverse" style="margin-right:70px">GALLERY</a>
</div>

    <div id="image_carousel">
        <div id="foo4">
            <img src="images/small/1.jpg" alt="basketball" width="140" height="140" />
            <img src="images/small/2.jpg" alt="beachtree" width="140" height="140" />
            <img src="images/small/3.jpg" alt="cupcackes" width="140" height="140" />
            <img src="images/small/4.jpg" alt="hangmat" width="140" height="140" />
            <img src="images/small/5.jpg" alt="new york" width="140" height="140" />
            <img src="images/small/6.jpg" alt="laundry" width="140" height="140" />
            <img src="images/small/7.jpg" alt="mom son" width="140" height="140" />
            <img src="images/small/8.jpg" alt="picknick" width="140" height="140" />
            <img src="images/small/9.jpg" alt="shoes" width="140" height="140" />
            <img src="images/small/10.jpg" alt="paris" width="140" height="140" />
            <img src="images/small/11.jpg" alt="sunbading" width="140" height="140" />
            <img src="images/small/12.jpg" alt="yellow couple" width="140" height="140" />
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#image_carousel {
    padding: 15px 0 15px 40px;
}
#image_carousel img {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 9px;
    margin: 7px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
#clearfix {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Re arrange Sequence

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.0-packed.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.css">
```

and then try